# Is this proof of the irrationality of the square root of any prime number correct?

Tags: solution-verification, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

i was trying to proof that $\sqrt{2}$ was irrational without looking the standard proof, and after hours of head banging i ended up with an argument for the irrationality of the square root of any prime, the argument goes like this:

[1/premise]for any prime number $P, \sqrt{P} = \frac{a}{b}$ were [2]$a,b$ are coprime

[3] every natural number can be described by a product of primes.
$x = p_0^{y_0}  p_1^{y_1}  p_0^{y_2} ... p_n^{y_n}$

[4]the exponents of all the prime factors of any perfect square are all even

$x^2 = x*x = (p_0^{y_0}  p_1^{y_1}  p_0^{y_2} ... p_n^{y_n}) * (p_0^{y_0}  p_1^{y_1}  p_0^{y_2} ... p_n^{y_n}) = p_0^{2y_0}  p_1^{2y_1}  p_0^{2y_2} ... p_n^{2y_n}$

by the premise $\sqrt{P} = \frac{a}{b}$ we can square both sides and multiply by $b^2$, then we get $a^2=P*b^2$, so $a^2$ is divisible by $P$, and by [2] we know that b is not.

therefore the prime factors of $a^2 = P^1 * (p_0^{2y_0}  p_1^{2y_1}  p_0^{2y_2} ... p_n^{2y_n})$, the exponent of $P$ is 1, entering in contraction with [4] so the premise is false.

Comment: Your argument is correct. You are using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to calculate the parity of the exponents on the prime factors of a square. There are proofs that use much less.

Comment: You use more than [3], namely that the product representation is *unique* (up to some ordering, of course), for if $x$ would have $2$ different representations then the powers in $x*x$ need not be even. The uniqueness is true but not so trivial to prove.
If you want to have some fun, you can try to prove by similar means that $\sqrt[k]{n}$ ($n,k$ natural numbers) is either integer or irrational.

Comment: Generally, one feature of the proofs you refer to is that they avoid using Unique Factorization.  That's a much deeper result than the irrationality claim.

Comment: you may not need to go so deep.  $a$ and $b$ are co prime so $a^2 = pb^2$ would mean $b^2|a^2$ but $b$ is coprime to $a$ (you have to prove Euclid's Lemma first) that is only possible of $b^2 = 1$ or $b = 1$ so $\sqrt p = a$ and $a^2 = p$ which is impossible as $p$ is prime.  Lulu's comment about the unique factorization theorem is valid.  The UFT is so deep and broad it pretty much proves only perfect squares have a rational square root as an immediate corollary.